# how to get autofs to mount a partition as rw?

Tags: linux, mount, autofs

I got autofs to mount a partition. It works fine, except I can't get it to mount with write privileges to regular users.

I tried with this in auto.master:

`/misc  /etc/auto.misc --timeout=60`

and this in auto.misc:

`data       -fstype=vfat,rw   :/dev/sda5`

And I didn't get it to work.

When I was using fstab, the solution was to let users mount it passing the user mount option. Is there a way to make autofs mount stuff as the current user?

EDIT: forgot to mention, using the user option in auto.misc also didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to make autofs mount
>   stuff as the current user?

Not really, but what you could do is setup a group for users who will be allowed to have access to that resource, add all the users to the group, and then finally pass the gid, umask, and dmask [options](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) to set the group, and permissions the fat filesystem will use once it is mounted.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. It's not an elegant solution, but it works. It's also good because it gives me control over who can mount it. I don't need it right now, but who knows!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding ",user" after the "rw" in auto.misc?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. Updated the question to mention that, I had forgotten.